# Benefits of SAML vs straight HTTP Post

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am researching different Single Sign On options.  It seems to me that SAML while is a great solution if we look at 3rd party vendors it is somewhat out of our price range.  We are also looking at implementing our own solution... but, some of the services we want to use - just to enable SAML logins they want to charge.  If I know all of my user's credentials what is the security risk/downside of just doing an HTTP POST with the credentials to these different services?  Some of the SSO providers do this when SAML is not enabled as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using SAML would remove the need for users and Service Providers to deal with password issues like reset, expiry, recovery, rotation etc. completely, aside from managing the synchronization process that now needs to happen between IDP and SPs.

In addition to that there's the the amount of brittle, costly and awkward reverse engineering of SP login webpages that needs to be done and maintained(!) by any IDP that operates a password vaulting system (which is what you describe).

Also, introducing an SSO system allows you to concentrate user authentication efforts and improvements in one place only, making it simpler to introduce strong or second factor authentication for all services at once, without requiring support for that by each SP.

Last but not least: password vaulting systems still involve passwords that are distributed over different systems/SPs and that cannot be (completely) hidden from the user. That makes it hard or impossible to ensure that access to all systems is turned off at once e.g. when a user leaves the organization.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that answers the downside.  And the last one is a security concern yes, but if you or anyone else has security concerns beyond that I'd be interested to hear them.

Comment: there are the usual password concerns, e.g.: a) not a strong way of authentication and b) users are likely to reuse the same password across different services so that SP A would be able to impersonate the user at SP B

Comment: The starting point for the password would have to be locked down.  So they need to create a better password from the get go.  At least for us, we still provision most of their accounts or have some control over the syncing of passwords and disabling of accounts.